# Why does digitally signing with Adobe Reader cause Windows Cryptographic errors

Tags: windows, adobe, digital-signature, citrix

My organization deploys Adobe Reader 32 bit via Citrix Workspace from a server running Windows Server 2016 64 bit. We cannot install 64 bit Reader at this time.

Recently we have begun to run into an issue where when some users attempt to digitally sign, the 'Sign' button does not respond when clicked. It will change color to indicate the click happens, but nothing occurs after. The application is not frozen and still functions, you simply cannot sign.

The only working resolution we have found is to move the user to a new Citrix server/session. This has 100% efficacy, but some users will eventually experience the issue again. We have yet to find a way to force the issue to happen.

I am looking for suggestions on what troubleshooting steps we can try that haven't already been. Or things we can look at to try and gain more insight. This issue has been present in our environment since 2020. It used to only happen to 1-2 users per week, but now it's occurring several times per day. We cannot find anything to indicate what the issue is or what caused the uptick in Incidents.

We have attempted to use Adobe support but due to reader being a free application they will not provide any. We have also tried every solution available out there.

If you disable the 'Modern UI for digital signatures' within the application, when you click the 'Sign' button it will throw one of two errors:

- "The Windows Cryptographic Service Provider reported an error: The profile for the user is a temporary profile. Error Code: 2148073508"
- "The Windows Cryptographic Service Provider reported an error: Keyset does not exist. Error code: 2148073494".